# Conseguir el nombre de una promesa - async

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ecmascript-6

tengo entendido que si tienes una función puedes obtener el nombre con la propiedad `name` y si es una clase puedes obtener el nombre `prototype.name` pero como consigo el nombre de una promesa, el problema es el siguiente 
tengo varias funciones tipo `async` y cuando tienen un error  me salta el evento 
`unhandledRejection` el cual me retorna dos parametros `error` y `promise` ahora lo que quiero es imprimir el nombre de la funcion que retorna el error
un ejemplo de mi codigo

```
app.get('/', async function index (req, res, next) {
  throw new Error('hay ja jay, un error compadre')
}) 
process.on('unhandledRejection', (err, p) => {
    console.error(`a ocurrido en la funcion ${p} el siguiente error: `, err)    
})
```

resumen lv5:
como consigo el nombre de  `p`

edito:

el código que proviene de un api json realizada en express y tengo diferentes rutas cada controlador de un ruta utiliza una función `callback` que puede ser una función anónima normal, una promesa o una función `async`, este ultimo tipo de función la utilizo por cuestiones de lectura en el código 
y se comporta en realidad como si fuera una promesa.

Ahora es una buena practica para el debuging en nodejs tener las funciones 
nombradas asi que tengo la funcion de la siguiente manera

```
async function index (req, res, next) {

}
```

estas funciones se capturan los errores con `try` y `catch` como cualquier y al ser un
`callback` de un endpoint de express recibe los parámetros `req`, `res` y `next`
lo normal es pasar el error a `next` para que lo maneje el error handler de express
pero lo que quiero es hacer saltar el error handler del propio node `unhandledRejection`
y ver si puedo registrar con el nombre de la promesa de este caso osea 'index'

Comment: con `reject("error ein index"); ` dentro de la funcion intenta hacer un new Promise(resolve,reject)=>{}

Comment: la cuestión es que la función `index` se convierte en una promesa al utilizar `async` así que me lanza el evento  y me retorna la consola "a ocurrido en la funcion [object Promise] el siguiente error:  hay ja jay, un error compadre" donde `[object Promise]` me gustaria que saliera index

Comment: voy a hacer mi respuesta intepretando que tu codigo funciona

Answer (score 2):

Leyendo la [documentacion de arrojar excepciones](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Error)  
de Mozilla puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Ver la funcion que te arrojo el error
- Mostrar la traza desde donde fallo
- Mostrar el `'hay ja jay, un error compadre'`

Un Ejemplo practico seria a continuacion :

```js
const miPromesa = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      throw new Error('hay ja jay, un error compadre');
  });
};

const main = async () => {
  try {
    await miPromesa();
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error(`Chispas!! me han retornado un ${ex.name}  su mensaje es "${ex.message}" `)
    console.info(`la traza del error fue : ${ex.stack}`)

  }
};

main();
```

Asumiendo que tu codigo esta bien quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
app.get('/', async function index (req, res, next) {
  Promise.reject(new Error('hay ja jay, un error compadre'))
}) 
process.on('unhandledRejection', ( p, err) => {
    console.error(`Chispas!! me han retornado un ${err.name}  su mensaje es "${err.message}" `) 
console.info(`la traza del error fue : ${err.stack}`)
})
```

---

Ahora el deber ser para el manejo de errores de una Promesa es usando resolve y reject el codigo deberia ser :

```js
    const miPromesa = () => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reject('hay ja jay, un error compadre en linea 2 al retorna nueva promesa verifique parametros' );
      });
    };

    const main = async () => {
      try {
        await miPromesa();
      } catch (ex) {
        console.error(`Chispas!! me han retornado un Error ${ex}`)


      }
    };

    main();
```

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta lo que pasa es lo siguiente nodejs tiene eventos para manejar los errores y uno de esos eventos es `unhandledRejection` el cual me captura el error de las promesas cuando no se utiliza un `catch` este tiene una función anónima que me da el error y la promesa lo que deseo aunque no se si se puede es obtener el nombre de la promesa

Comment: encontre el error, en el `unhandledRejection` las palabras estan invertidas, fue mas profunda la [investigacion](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html)